# Python import matplotlib.pyplot not working

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, easy-install

I have tried easy_install matplotlib and have the following:

matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg

installed in my Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.

When I move to a different folder to make use of contents in that folder and try to

"import matplotlib.pyplot" it says : ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

This makes me think that the easy_install has been done incorrectly. This question is quite basic but I am working with mac osx and other than learn that it is incredibly hard to install this module on osx I have learnt little else from most sources so I would like to know if anyone on SO can help me with my problem. I am a python novice and would really appreciate the help.

Comment: First, can you `import matplotlib`? Second, have is that `~/Library`, `/Library`, or `/System/Library`? Exactly what `easy_install` line did you run, and what `python` did you run. (More generally, do you have non-Apple Python installations on your system? If so, how did you install them? Which one are you trying to use `matplotlib` with? Which `python` and `easy_install` show up when you use the `which` command?)

Comment: Also, you really should use `pip` instead of `easy_install` whenever possible. If you're using the stock Apple Python, I believe in 10.7 and 10.8 they give you `easy_install` but not `pip`—but you can fix that just by doing `sudo easy_install pip`, and then you can use `pip` for everything else (except `readline` and a handful of other much more uncommon libraries).

Comment: ~/Library, the easy install line I ran was the following:   sudo easy_install -m matplotlib

Comment: If you're doing `sudo`, why did it end up in `~/Library`? Have you done any kind of extra configuration (or used virtualenv or something)? Also, please answer _all_ of the questions, not just one or two, or it's impossible to debug your problem.

Comment: I apologize it is in the system/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. No extra configuration, sorry for the confusion. Just the sudo easy_install -m matplotlib. The version of python I am running is python 2.7 on mac os X. I am using matplotlib with python 2.7 itself which is the default version of python on my mac.

Comment: your advice for pip install has worked. I am still unaware of what the problems with easy_install matplotlib are but pip install did work thank you for that tip abarnert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you should always use `pip` instead of `easy_install`, except for a handful of libraries (all of which document that fact, and the only ones you're likely to care about are `readline`, and of course `pip` itself).

If you're on OS X 10.7 or 10.8, using the Apple-installed Python, you have `easy_install` built-in, but not `pip`. To fix that:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

And now, you can do this:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Normally, this won't actually solve the kind of problem you're having. The reason to use `pip` is that `easy_install` has no uninstall functionality, it handles upgrades badly, it can end up leaving stuff part-way installed when it fails, it doesn't work right with virtualenv, etc.

But it sounds like you got lucky, and this change magically fixed your problem. We could try to diagnose the original problem. (Why were you using `-m` with `easy_install`? Does `pip install --egg` work? And so on.) But I'm guessing you're happy with the result and just want to leave well-enough alone.

For future readers who come along, it seems like `sudo easy_install -m matplotlib` on the stock Apple 10.7 Python 2.7 does not work, but `sudo pip install matplotlib` does, and that may be good enough for them as well.